After Upgrade to 24.04 black screen with error messages
This is what showing me after I rebbot
Yesterday I used forced commands to update ubuntu to the 24.04 LTS version. After the downloading has completed, it automatically rebooted. The black screen with a cursor has been shown.
After that I rebooted manually using power button then this screen pops up everytime. I have tried recovery mode and generic, even tried to upgrade using F3, Alt and Ctrl key, but nothing happened.
Please help!!
